# The method getParentFragment() is undefined for the type MyDialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm getting an error "The method getParentFragment() is undefined for the type MyDialogFragment"

I'm not sure why I am getting this error, as far I am concerned, I have got everything set up correctly.

Any guidance would be of help, thanks.

```
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.app.WallpaperManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
private Button ButtonOk;
private Button ButtonCancel;

public MyDialogFragment() {
    // Empty constructor required for DialogFragment
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.prompt, container);
    ButtonOk = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    ButtonCancel = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    getDialog().setTitle("Set Wallpaper?");

    ButtonOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub



                    //Here

            ((ImageDetailFragment)(MyDialogFragment.this.getParentFragment())).onDialogOKPressed();
            dismiss();




        }

    });

    ButtonCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            MyDialogFragment.this.dismiss();

        }
    });

    return view;

}
}
```

Imports from my Main Fragment:

```
import android.app.WallpaperManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can do a walkaround with creating a method to set the parent fragment from that fragment, no idea why the getParentFragment method fails. Maybe youre using Fragment from support lib and DialogFragment from main android.app lib, or the opposite?

Comment: exactly - import android.app.DialogFragment;
and later on import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;